# Laravel custom pivot with incrementing key observer event error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a custom pivot model with an incrementing id. I have set up an Observer, and I get events for things like `attach`, `updateExistingPivot`, etc. However, the object that is passed into the observer functions does not include the 'id' field. 
This gives me an error when I try to save a related model to the custom pivot (Audit model below).

```
class Audit extends Model
{
    public function auditable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
  public function accounts()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Account')
    ->withPivot('id')
    ->using('App\Models\AccountUser');
  }
}

class Account extends Model
{
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')
    ->withPivot('id')
    ->using('App\Models\AccountUser');
  }
}

class AccountUser extends Pivot
{
  public $incrementing = true;

  public function account()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Account');
  }

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
  }

  public function audits()
  {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Audit', 'auditable');
  }
}
```

If I do
`$user->accounts()->updateExistingPivot($acct_id, ['description' => $description]);`
an updating event fires, but it does not contain in `id`:

```
(
    [user_id] => 18000
    [account_id] => 111389
    [description] => My Description
)
```

Then if I try to save a new Audit to the custom pivot, I get an error because there is no `auditable_id` for the SQL statement:

```
public function updating(AccountUser $auditable)
{
  $audit = new Audit();
  ...
  $auditable->audits()->save($audit);
}
```

Generates

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'auditable_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `audits` (`auditable_id`, `auditable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, App\\Models\\AccountUser, 2020-04-02 13:24:53, 2020-04-02 13:24:53))
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is your end goal? What data are you trying to save?

Comment: @MikeRoss I have edited the `updating` function parameter to make it more clear. When the `AccountUser` updating event fires, I create an `Audit` with the intention of saving it to the accountModels `audits` relationship. However, the `Audit` is a polymorphic relationship that many other models use, so it has the `auditable_id` field that expects an `id` field to exist on parent model (AccountUser in this case). The AccountUser is $incrementing, and does have an `id` field when I directly create an instance, but not  when the event is triggered via setting the `using` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was fixed in the Laravel 7.x branch, while I am still on 6.x.
i.e. in 7.x, the custom pivot events will have the `id` field (and all others) if it exists.